# PL SQL Nested IF ELSE with Cursor

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I have three cursors declared CUR_AD1, CUR_AD1_C, CUR_AD_2. All they contain is result coming from a 3 mere select statements which works fine.

Later on I have the following statements:

```
BEGIN

    FOR AD1_REC IN CUR_AD1 LOOP

      V_ORG_NAME := AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE1;


    IF V_ORG_NAME = AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE1 THEN
        INSERT INTO DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE 
        (CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, CCTR_PERSON_ID, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE1, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE2, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE3, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE4, 
        ORG_NAME, DEPT_NAME, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE1, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE2, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE3, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE4, 
        STATE, CITY, COUNTRY_NAME, ZIP_CODE, EXTRACT_DATE) 
        VALUES
        (AD1_REC.CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, AD1_REC.CCTR_PERSON_ID, AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE1, AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE2, AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE3, AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE4, 
         V_ORG_NAME, '', '', AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE2, AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE3, AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE4, 
         AD1_REC.STATE, AD1_REC.CITY, AD1_REC.COUNTRY_NAME, AD1_REC.ZIP_CODE, SYSDATE);

    ELSIF V_ORG_NAME = AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE2 THEN
      FOR AD2_REC IN CUR_AD2 LOOP

        INSERT INTO DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE 
        (CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, CCTR_PERSON_ID, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE1, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE2, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE3, SRC_ADDRESS_LINE4, 
        ORG_NAME, DEPT_NAME, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE1, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE2, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE3, TGT_ADDRESS_LINE4,
        STATE, CITY, COUNTRY_NAME, ZIP_CODE, EXTRACT_DATE) 
        VALUES
        (AD2_REC.CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, AD2_REC.CCTR_PERSON_ID, AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE1, AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE2, AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE3, AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE4, 
         AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE2, NULL, AD2_REC.TGT_ADDRESS_LINE1, NULL, AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE3, AD2_REC.ADDRESS_LINE4, 
         AD2_REC.STATE, AD2_REC.CITY, AD2_REC.COUNTRY_NAME, AD2_REC.ZIP_CODE, SYSDATE);
         END LOOP;
         END IF;

END LOOP;                
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR' || SQLERRM);
RAISE;    
END;
```

When I compile the body I keep getting the following errors:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PLS-00302: component 'ZIP_CODE' must be declared
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

There is no problem with the tables whatsoever. I think it has to do something with the how I am putting my control statements. Any help is highly appreciated.

DDL for Table DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE

```
  CREATE TABLE "CALSEED_OWNER"."DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE" 
   (    "CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "CCTR_PERSON_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "SRC_ADDRESS_LINE1" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SRC_ADDRESS_LINE2" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SRC_ADDRESS_LINE3" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SRC_ADDRESS_LINE4" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ORG_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DEPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TGT_ADDRESS_LINE1" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TGT_ADDRESS_LINE2" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TGT_ADDRESS_LINE3" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TGT_ADDRESS_LINE4" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "COUNTRY_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ZIP_CODE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "EXTRACT_DATE" DATE, 
    "STREET" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "STREET_CONTD" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)

CURSOR CUR_AD2 IS         
        SELECT CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 'AL2' AL,ADDRESS_LINE2 
        FROM STG_RT2_PERSON_ADDRESS WHERE UPPER(ADDRESS_LINE2) IN 
        ( SELECT UPPER(ORG_NAME) FROM STG_RT2_ORGANIZATION
        WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ORG_NAME, '[0-9]') 
        AND NOT (LOWER(ORG_NAME) LIKE 'unknown' OR LOWER(ORG_NAME) LIKE 'no address%'
        OR ORG_NAME ='-' OR ORG_NAME=' '));
```

Comment: Logic seems strange to start with. `V_ORG_NAME` is set to `AD1_REC.ADDRESS_LINE1`, then immediate compared to the same value. If this is supposed to be a `NULL` check, the perhaps usage of `IS NULL` would be more clear. Also, to debug, don't catch and raise the exception, then you will see the line number. Remove the `IF` statement altogether and try both statements individually to see which (or if both) causes grief. Probably need to see the definitions as well.

Comment: perhaps you are right about the null check thought. this code was written by another colleague of mine so I am not sure why he did that. But from what you are saying it seems i need to put equality check outside of the loop? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you post a describe of DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE and the cursors?

Comment: As Roger said, please post the description of the cursors - **CUR_AD2**, to be precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can use

```
DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace;
```

Make sure all alias in your cursors (not only your table) match the columns you are trying to access e.g.

```
FOR x IN SELECT zip_code zipCode FROM myTable LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(x.zip_Code)
END LOOP;
```

The example breaks because x contains zipCode instead of zip_code.

With the information you provided, we can't give any further help, post a describe of your table aswell as your cursors declaration or make a compilable example.

This is useful http://sqlfiddle.com/

**Edit**

The problem is your cursor declaration

```
  SELECT
    CCTR_PERSON_ADDRESS_ID,
    'AL2' AL,
    ADDRESS_LINE2,
    ZIP_CODE -- ADD THIS FOR THE ZIP CODE, YOU NEED TO ADD ALL THE OTHER COLUMNS ASWELL...
 FROM
    STG_RT2_PERSON_ADDRESS
  WHERE
    UPPER(ADDRESS_LINE2) IN
    (
      SELECT
        UPPER(ORG_NAME)
      FROM
        STG_RT2_ORGANIZATION
      WHERE
        NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ORG_NAME, '[0-9]')
      AND NOT
        (
          LOWER(ORG_NAME) LIKE 'unknown'
        OR LOWER(ORG_NAME) LIKE 'no address%'
        OR ORG_NAME ='-'
        OR ORG_NAME =' '
        )
    );
```

Every CUR_AD_2 is a record on your result set, therefore it has its same number of columns and names, in your query, you have only 3 columns but you are trying to access a lot of them (like zip code) that are not in the cursor; make sure to add ZIP_CODE and all the other columns needed. Or just delete them from the INSERT statement

Comment: What I have realized is its not the zip code. Even lets say I remove zip code the error is back again pointing at the second last column. I think there is some control statement issue after i start the second loop.

Comment: Now the moment I add TGT_ADDRESS_LINE1 column, it says that loop index variable 'AD2_REC' use is invalid. Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18206/discussion-between-roger-and-bytekoder)

Answer (score 0):

Please check zip_code spelling matchecs column name in the table

Comment: Its not the zip code even if I remove that the error pointer goes to next last column... I think its the whole block.